# Return value 0 when SUM by GROUPBY does not return entity - Sequelize ORM

Tags: sql, database, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a ranking where the projects entity can receive votes, represented by another table, the votes entity. However, when no one voted for project x, the entity votes does not know about the specific project. I'm using ORM Sequelize and I'm using SUM/GROUPBY method to join common records. When there are records, everything goes well. The problem is when there is no vote registered for a given project in the vote table, my wish is that this project without votes, would also be returned with a default value of 0. I've read that it has a default value like "isnull(sum, 0)", something like that, but I don't know where to put it, because in my head the votes entity will have to go back to the projects entity to check which ones didn't add up, so I don't know if it fits in my case.

```
 let response = await Votes.findAll({
  limit,
  offset,
  attributes: ['project', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('factor')), 'votes']],
  group: ['project', "project_.address" ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Projects,
      as: 'project_',
      attributes: ["address","name"],
    }],
  raw: true,
  order: [[sequelize.literal('votes'), 'DESC']],
})

  return res.json(response);
```

Comment: Have you tried `required: false`?

Comment: No... where ???

Comment: I'm not that familiar with sequelize.  But if you want projects which have no votes, wouldn't you do some kind of `Projects.findAll` ... and in the `where` condition for Votes, use `required: false` to allow projects which have no votes.  Something like that.  Look into how sequelize handles outer joins (specifically, LEFT JOIN).  The default behavior without that is like an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant on the `includes` condition, not the `where`.

Comment: ohh ok... yeah, doesn't work... but thanks man

Comment: Please share your votes and project models

Comment: Projects model - ( id, address, name )
Votes model - ( id, project_id , factor = 1 )